# GC static object references to null

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I understood that:

- Nullifying local references is more useful for readability than actual GC collection (it won't make a real difference)
- Objects referred to by static references are not eligible until the Classloader gets collected itself (since it references the Class object, that in turn references the static variables)

What does actually happen behind the scenes, when setting static references to objects explicitly to null?
What happens to the original object that was originally stored in heap?

Comment: Nulling local references can serve as a warning that the code is written by someone who doesn't really understand what they're doing. Otherwise it's has no advantage.

Comment: `Nullifying local references is more useful for readability than actual GC collection (it won't make a real difference)`---it _can_ make a difference between an OutOfMemoryError and no error.

Comment: A common misconception is to think that there will something happen, when an object becomes unreachable, aka garbage. The truth is *nothing* will happen for ordinary objects. The memory management works by copying or compacting the *still reachable* objects, so that the memory area containing garbage only can be considered free memory per se, without the need for explicit freeing actions.

Comment: @Holger Thanks, yours is actually the most useful answer that explains the process more clearly. Not sure why it is seldomly explained this way, as it is imo the best clarification.

Comment: It’s often considered an implementation detail (well, it *is* an implementation detail, but a detail of the most widespread implementations…) or too complication for an introduction. [This document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/memorymanagement-whitepaper-1-150020.pdf), while outdated, gives a good overview about the different algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the view of the object it does not matter whether the reference to it was from a static field, or from somewhere else. As soon as there are no more references to it it is eligible for garbage collection. When it actually get garbage collected depends on the object pool it is in, and the garbage colection strategy being used.

Comment: Thanks, I was overthinking.

Answer (score 1):

There is no significant difference between those two points "behind the scenes".

The different effects are simply due to the lifetime of the references themselves. A local variable goes out of scope once it is no longer used in a method or at the latest once the method exits. Static fields keep existing as long as the class does, which in many cases is as long as the application lifetime.

That means a local reference is unlikely to significantly extend the lifetime of an object significantly in most cases (although there are exceptions) while a static reference does if the object would otherwise be shortlived.

Answer (score 1):

> Nullifying local references is more useful for readability

If you mean that it clutters the code and makes it less readable, then I agree.

> ... it won't make a real difference

I some rare cases, it can make a difference. But don't do it, unless you're perfectly sure that it's important (if you feel like doing it more than once per hundred methods, it's probably wrong).

> What does actually happen behind the scenes, when setting static references to objects explicitly to null?

Nothing special. If this was the last reference, the object gets eligible for GC. But that's the same as with every other object/reference.

> What happens to the original object that was originally stored in heap?

Nothing at all as it's only the reference what gets nullified. The object gets collected one day (if it was the last reference), but again: nothing special.